# What is issue/feature 150 in Parsec?

Tags: git, github, haskell, version-control, parsec

I am looking through the parsec github repository (currently at version 3.1.16.1) on the master branch. As of the time of writing this, the latest commit on master has commit id 1f542120d9adc5e22f8791a6d595210e93c6c389.

If I run `git branch -a` (to see local and remote branches), I see that there is a branch named "remotes/origin/issue150". Here is the output of the command.

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/issue150
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/wip/ghc86
  remotes/origin/wip/travis
```

I checked out this branch (commit id 76227d9006154cedd4861b9ff552aa1fbc2d27c2 currently). I saw this message on github about the branch issue150: "This branch is 1 commit ahead, 7 commits behind master." I ran `git diff HEAD~1` to see what this branch changed relative to the commit in master history that it branched off of.
Amongst other things, the issue150 branch adds a test module `Features.Feature150`.

My question is not about the code itself. Rather, I am interested in finding where this feature was assigned the number 150. Is there a forum for features that I am not aware of like the "Issues" page for tab for github repositories? If so, does a similar forum exist for all github repositories?

Comment: Is that not just a [Github issue ID](https://github.com/haskell/parsec/issues/150)? Seems to be, since [the latest commit](https://github.com/haskell/parsec/commit/76227d9006154cedd4861b9ff552aa1fbc2d27c2) mentions the `string'` identifier mentioned in the issue.

Comment: Someone named the branch `issue150`.

Comment: The process for contributors, including the process for filing issues, bugs, and feature requests is explained on the Parsec homepage.

Comment: @JörgWMittag By homepage, do you mean the homepage on hackage, https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec? On that page, the only mention of the word "feature" is this: "Issues (bugs, feature requests or otherwise feedback) may be reported in the Github issue tracker for this project." However, there is nowhere near 150 issues on Github for parsec. At the time of writing, there are 34 open and 40 closed (74 total, less than 150).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Never mind, Github added an automatic filter to the Issues that I saw. I removed the filters and saw that there are (at the time of writing), in fact, 44 open and 122 closed Issues on Github for the parsec repository. I found that there is an Issue with id #150. I will write an answer detailing that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate You were right. I simply had trouble finding the Issue with that id because Github seems to automatically add filters when I go to the Issues tab on the repo page (see comment replying to @JörgWMittag)